# What is the method signature when it uses an external param name in Swift

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, selector

I'm using an NSTimer object in my Swift code, which requires a method signature to be passed to its 'selector' parameter in order to recurrently perform said method. When the method  signature does not have an external parameter name i.e.

```
func timerMethod(internal: String) { ... }
```

I can pass the timer object this signature as so:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0,
        target: self,
        selector: Selector("timerMethod:"),
        userInfo: userInfo,
        repeats: true)
```

However, if I give the method a signature with an external parameter name, such as:

```
func timerMethod(external internal: String) { ... }
```

I can't figure out how to call the method. I attempted to log it using:

```
println("\(__FUNCTION__)")
```

Which logs the following:

```
timerMethod(external:)
```

But whenever I try this or any of the following, I receive 'unrecognized selector' exceptions:

```
timerMethod:
timerMethod:external
timerMethod:external:
timerMethod:(external)
timerMethod:(external:)
timerMethod(external):
```

Stumped for now. Anybody running into something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `timerMethodWithExternal:` you can test that with `object_getClass(t).instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("timerMethodWithExternal:"))`

i used following code to introspect

```
func with(t: Test, inout count : CUnsignedInt) -> UnsafePointer<Method> {
    var mc : CUnsignedInt = 0
    return class_copyMethodList(object_getClass(t), &count)
}

var i=0
var mc : CUnsignedInt = 0
var t = Test()
var mlist = with(t,&mc)
var n : Int = Int(mc)
for (i=0; i<n;i++) {
    println(sel_getName(method_getName(mlist[i])))
}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. I'm really surprised that this works. Thanks Christian.

Answer (score 1):

Although the signature for your method doesn't look correct, in Swift you pass a `selector` simply as the string name.  The Apple documentation:

> Because string literals can be automatically converted to selectors,
>   you can pass a string literal to any method that accepts a selector.

As for the signature of `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`, the Apple documentation states (See NSTimer documentation, Swift info):

> The selector should have the following signature: timerFireMethod:
>   (including a colon to indicate that the method takes an argument). The
>   timer passes itself as the argument, thus the method would adopt the
>   following pattern:

```
func timerFireMethod(timer: NSTimer) { }
```

When you define your own method as:

```
func timerMethod(external internal: String) { ... }
```

then you are not meeting the required signature.  The expected call is:

```
someMethod(timer: ...)
```

but your call would be:

```
someMethod(external: ...)
```

Besides, the argument should be of type `NSTimer`, not `String`.  You were probably lucky that your first attempt worked.

Comment: Apologies, I misled with the String typed argument, I'd copied that signature from another function. It actually is using an NSTimer as the type in the method I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I ran into the same problem and was also able to confirm the proper selector name by inspecting the [Xcode-generated header file](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) in the derived data folder for my project.

Just search for your method's name `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and for the original poster's example you would find that the selector to be used is `timerMethodWithExternal:` (from its Objective-C definition).

I believe this header is generated even for pure Swift projects, the project I tested on had some Objective-C in it though.